# Triple condition in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to press proper Icon. so I think at first I need to identify which element to pick so I do that by class "name" and after I want to Click icon in same line but another class.

HTML

```
<tr class="container">
    <td class="name"> </td>
    <td class="icons">
        <icon class="Searching element">
                </td></tr>
```

I have no idea how to do triple condition.

Comment: //td[@class='name']/following::td[@class='icons']/i .So you get the td class name and then want the following td class icons and then click the i tag?

Comment: I want to get td class='name' and in here I want to make a  condition for specific value as for example class='name' where name ='Jack' and later I want to find icon belongs to the same line

Answer (score 0):

You can use logic operators to create better conditions in an xpath expression. For example, the xpath: `//td[@class='name' and @name ='Jack']` locates the td element based on those two attributes.

If you want to locate based on an attribute and the text on element, you can do something like this `//td[@class='name' and contains(text(), 'Jack' )]`

Here is a good reference about xpath: https://devhints.io/xpath

Comment: I tried as you introduced and I used sibling option from site u gave but still it's not working. Here is a line of code: `By.XPath("//*[@class='name' and contains(text(),'Jack')]//following-sibling::[@class='icons')]/[@class='delete')]"));` 
But I am not sure if I did use correctly sibling option.

Comment: The following-sibling usage seems ok. But I found some typos in your xpath line:
`following-sibling::[@class='icons')]` the parenthesis after "icons" and `/[@class='delete')]` the same parenthesis after delete. Also if your page works on Chrome, you can use the built-in xpath tester to check your xpath expression. Press F12 and CTRL+F on the page source code. it'll open a field where you can type your xpath and check it.